# C++ Pointer array and buffering

Tags: c++

I have a problem while reading from a file.
The code below ends with runtime error after like 100 loop, after tracing found that the 
`mybuff` my doesn't reintialize with (`mybuff = new char [1024];`) because after debugging i still see the prvious message at the end of it.
and the problem happens when I try to fill `sendbuff` because same issue.
the error saying aboout "Access violation reading location" happens at this step ( `sprintf(sendbuff,mybuff )`)

any idea how to solve this issue?

```
char sendbuff[1024];
char * mybuff = new char[];
While(....){
    mybuff = new char [1024];
    myfile.read(mybuff ,bufsize);
    sprintf(sendbuff,mybuff );
    ibytessent=0;    
    tmpCount = strlen(sendbuff);
    ibufferlen = strlen(sendbuff);
    ibytessent = send(s,sendbuff,ibufferlen,0);
delete [] mybuff ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you call `ifstream::read()` is wrong. `read()` doesnot  add the null character at the end for you and you need to check the `eofbit` and `failbit`.

Quote from the manual,

> The number of characters successfully read and stored by this function
>   can be accessed by calling member gcount.

Comment: Sorry the error doesnt not happen at the read, but seems it append at the begining of the pointer array which causes "the error saying aboout "Access violation reading location" happens at this step ( sprintf(sendbuff,mybuff ))"

Comment: There's a difference between where the error *happens*, and where it is *exhibited*. If `read()` does not add the null character, then `sprintf()` will read past the end of the buffer, if there are no null characters in it by chance. So that's where you'll see the effects of the error, but the actual error happened before, when you failed to add a null character to the end of your data. Debugging is a lot harder if you assume the actual error is always at the line reported by the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also think the run-time error is caused by the reason about read() function just as above, Also I don't think it's necessary to re-new 1024 bytes space at each iteration, why not reuse the buffer~

By the way, I try to repro your problem, I am not sure if the code below is the same with yours, and I don't get any run-time error

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int bufsize = 1024;
int main(){
    char sendbuff[1024];
    char * mybuff = new char[];
    std::ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open ("test.txt", std::ifstream::in);
    while(1){
        mybuff = new char [1024];
        ifs.read(mybuff ,bufsize);
        sprintf(sendbuff,mybuff );
        int ibytessent=0;    
        int tmpCount = strlen(sendbuff);
        int ibufferlen = strlen(sendbuff);
        //ibytessent = send(s,sendbuff,ibufferlen,0);
        delete [] mybuff ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the delete part